# Does a parent class always need a default or no-argument constructor even if the child class already has a defined constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, constructor, default-constructor

I cannot get this code to compile.

```
class Horse {
    private int age;
    Horse(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Pony extends Horse {
    private int age;
    Pony(int age) { //here compiler complains about no default constructor in parent class
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I know you must define a constructor for a child class when the parent class only has constructors with parameters, and that is what I have done. However, the compiler complains that the parent class has no default constructor.

Am I right to conclude that a parent class always needs a default or no-arg constructor? What if I want the parent and child class to only have constructors with parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I right to conclude that a parent class always needs a default or no-arg constructor?

No. The first thing a subclass constructor must do is to invoke one of the superclass constructors. If you don't, then the compiler calls the no-arg constructor of the superclass for you. But of course that fails if the superclass doesn't have one.

Your code should be:

```
class Pony extends Horse {
    Pony(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
}
```

See, the superclass already has an age field, and probably methods that use that field. So redeclaring one in the subclass is wrong and counter-productive.

Answer (score 2):

To make it compile to you need to call `super(int)` instead of calling `super()` implicitly.

```
Pony(int age) {
    super(age);
    this.age = age;
}
```

Then you may notice that both `Horse` and `Pony` have exactly the same field which holds exactly the same data. Why would `Pony` need to have the field `age` if the class `Pony` is based on (`Horse`) already defined this field?

```
Pony(int age) {
    super(age);
}
```

It's the beauty of inheritance: you may make use of anything that was already written in the base class.

---

> However, the compiler complains that the parent class has no default constructor.

It complains because, as I mentioned above, it failed to invoke `super()`.

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7</sup>

---

> What if I want the parent and child class to only have constructors with parameters?

Then the child class should always explicitly state what parent's constructor it wants to call.

---

> Am I right to conclude that a parent class always needs a default or no-arg constructor?

No, it's fine to have a parent class without the default constructor as long as its children don't invoke `super()`.